# Core Data one-to-many - how do i get objectAtIndex?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a class of Entry, and a class of Media. They're both in CoreData, and Entry has a one-to-many relationship with Media. The problem is, Media is an NSSet, and my tableview requires to know the detiails of a Media object at an index. How do i set this relationship up so it's something other than an NSSet, or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You choice is NSOrderedSet
If u target deployment more than 10.7 u can mark all relationships as ordered. and get objects by index.

Comment: Nevertheless, this worked on iOS too. Thanks. Do you know if it works on previous version of iOS, or is it only iOS5?

Comment: as i remember, it was together with lion, so ios5 may be requirement, but try,

Comment: When you create the relationship, click `Ordered` and it will make it an `NSOrderedSet`.

Answer (score 0):

> NSSet *entries = // fetch entries
>
> NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[entries allObjects]];

Then you can use objectAtIndex on the array